Mapping NULL values via CASE statement in Oracle SQL
I am trying to map few values using CASE statement. Everything seems to work fine except when there is a NULL value in the ID column. It shows 'OTHER STATE' from else instead of 'NO STATE' from WHEN NULL.
SELECT ID,CASE ID
WHEN 'TR' THEN 'TRIPURA'
WHEN 'MN' THEN 'MANIPUR'
WHEN 'AS' THEN 'ASSAM'
WHEN 'NL' THEN 'NAGALAND'
WHEN 'AN' THEN 'ARUNACHAL'
WHEN NULL THEN 'NO STATE'
ELSE 'OTHER STATE'
END AS STATE
FROM GEOGRAPHY;

the NULL works with DECODE but not working with CASE.Can NULL values be compared using CASE statement? DO NOT REFER NVL,NULL IF.I just want this with CASE.
I am trying to see if there is NULL value present in the list, it should return 'NO STATE'.

CASE checks whether the value of your column equals the value you provide. NULL is no value you can't compare with another, it can't equal anything, so you can't do it that way.
The only possible check is if it's NULL or not.
So, if you urgently want to use CASE only and avoid COALESCE or NVL, you could check if the id IS NULL before, something like this:
SELECT 
  id,
  CASE WHEN id IS NULL THEN 'NO STATE'
  ELSE CASE id
    WHEN 'TR' THEN 'TRIPURA'
    WHEN 'MN' THEN 'MANIPUR'
    WHEN 'AS' THEN 'ASSAM'
    WHEN 'NL' THEN 'NAGALAND'
    WHEN 'AN' THEN 'ARUNACHAL'
    ELSE 'OTHER STATE' END END AS STATE
FROM geography;

See this db<>fiddle
Sidenote: Long CASE constructs with many hard coded values are often no good idea, risky and bad to maintain. You could do better to add another column or even a mapping table and get rid of the CASE logic.

There are several options; here are a few of them.
Sample data:
SQL> with geography (id) as
  2    (select 'TR' from dual union all
  3     select 'TX' from dual union all
  4     select null from dual
  5    )

Various options:
  6  select id,
  7    -- your CASE expression
  8    case id when 'TR' then 'TRIPURA'
  9            when 'MN' then 'MANIPUR'
 10            when null then 'NO STATE'
 11            else 'OTHER STATE'
 12    end as state,
 13    -- switch to this one
 14    case when id is null then 'NO STATE'
 15         when id = 'TR' then 'TRIPURA'
 16         when id = 'MN' then 'MANIPUR'
 17         else 'OTHER STATE'
 18    end as state2,
 19    -- or use NVL
 20    case nvl(id, '-') when 'TR' then 'TRIPURA'
 21                      when 'MN' then 'MANIPUR'
 22                      when '-'  then 'NO STATE'
 23                      else 'OTHER STATE'
 24    end as state3
 25  from geography;

ID STATE       STATE2      STATE3
-- ----------- ----------- -----------
TR TRIPURA     TRIPURA     TRIPURA
TX OTHER STATE OTHER STATE OTHER STATE
   OTHER STATE NO STATE    NO STATE

SQL>


As @jonas-metzler correctly noted, a long CASE expression is hard to maintain. This following example shows an alternative way to get the same final result by using a LEFT JOIN and a CTE (that can be replaced by an actual table, if you feel more appropriate).
WITH state (id, name) as (
  SELECT NULL, 'NO STATE'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TR', 'TRIPURA'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'MN', 'MANIPUR'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'AS', 'ASSAM'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'NL', 'NAGALAND'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'AN', 'ARUNACHAL' FROM DUAL
) 
SELECT geo.id, COALESCE(sta.name, 'OTHER STATE') as state
FROM geography  geo
LEFT JOIN state sta ON ((sta.id IS NULL AND geo.id IS NULL) OR sta.id = geo.id)

Check the db<>fiddle here https://dbfiddle.uk/NJIJXLHH

Minimal effort solution, simply use the original ELSE for both 'OTHER STATE' and 'NO STATE'. (And you can remove the WHEN NULL entry.)
SELECT ID,CASE ID
WHEN 'TR' THEN 'TRIPURA'
WHEN 'MN' THEN 'MANIPUR'
WHEN 'AS' THEN 'ASSAM'
WHEN 'NL' THEN 'NAGALAND'
WHEN 'AN' THEN 'ARUNACHAL'
ELSE
    case when ID is not null then 'OTHER STATE' else 'NO STATE' end
END AS STATE
FROM GEOGRAPHY;

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/geA4PcVs (@Jonas Metzler's fiddle extended)

Looks nice too)
SELECT ID,CASE coalesce(ID,'<null>')
          WHEN 'TR' THEN 'TRIPURA'
          WHEN 'MN' THEN 'MANIPUR'
          WHEN 'AS' THEN 'ASSAM'
          WHEN 'NL' THEN 'NAGALAND'
          WHEN 'AN' THEN 'ARUNACHAL'
          WHEN '<null>' THEN 'NO STATE'
          ELSE 'OTHER STATE'
END AS STATE
FROM GEOGRAPHY;


Note that the string literal '<null>' isn't the same as the null value.
